# Add a group to a follower - Phaser 3

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I'm noob at Phaser 3 and trying to add a group (2 sprites) in a follower. The code works when I use a sprite at 'add.follower'.

```
function create () {

    var bola = this.add.group();

    bola.create(0, 0, 'bola15');
    bola.create(0, 0, 'bolasombra');

    var line1 = new Phaser.Curves.Line([ 100, 100, 500, 100 ]);
    var line2 = new Phaser.Curves.Line([ 500, 100, 500, 500 ]);

    path1 = this.add.path();

    path1.add(line1);
    path1.add(line2);

    var mover = this.add.follower(path1, 0, 0, bola);

    mover.startFollow({
        positionOnPath: true,
        duration: 3000,
        yoyo: false,
        repeat: 0,
        rotateToPath: false,
        verticalAdjust: true
    });
}
```

That's what I got:

[image: Error]

Any solution for that, or other way to make something like that?

Edit:

Have tried with 'container' and got the same result:

```
bola = this.add.container(0,0);
bola1 = this.add.sprite(0,0,'bola15');
bola2 = this.add.sprite(0,0,'bolasombra');  
bola.add(bola1);
bola.add(bola2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At current state, `PathFollower` is set up to take in only a single GameObject. Unfortunately, this means you'll have to add your group items to a follower one by one. You can set up a loop to run through your group items and create the path followers like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bola.children.entries.length; i++) {
  var mover = this.add.follower(path1, 0, 0, bola.children.entries[i].texture.key);

  mover.startFollow({
    positionOnPath: true,
    duration: 3000,
    yoyo: false,
    repeat: 0,
    rotateToPath: false,
    verticalAdjust: true
  });
}
```

Check [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/paths%5Cfollowers%5Cwave%20path.js) from the Phaser 3 labs to see another example of how you can use multiple items with the same path if the group structure isn't important to your game.

Comment: Yep... I've tried and works fine, but I thought that should be an 'elegant way'... Thanks! I gonna used that instead.